# How can I guarantee sequential order in multi-server Oracle RAC environment

Tags: oracle, oracle-rac

We are using a timestamp to ensure that entries in a log table are recorded sequentially, but we have found a potential flaw. Say, for example, we have two nodes in our RAC and the node timestamps are 1000ms off. Our app server inserts two log entries within 30ms seconds of each other. The first insert is serviced by Node1 and the second by Node2. With 1000ms difference between the two nodes, the timestamp could potentially show the log entries occurring in the wrong order! (I would just use a sequence, but our sequences are cached  for performance reasons... )

NTP sync doesn't help this situation because NTP has a fault tolerance of 128ms -- which leaves the door open for records to be recorded out of order when they occur more frequently than that.

I have a feeling I'm looking at this problem the wrong way. My ultimate goal is to be able to retrieve the actual sequence that log entries are recorded. It doesn't have to be by a timestamp column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [Oracle sequence with `ORDER` specified](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm) is guaranteed to return numbers in order across a RAC cluster.  So

```
create sequence my_seq
  start with 1
  increment by 1
  order;
```

Now, in order to do this, that means that you're going to be doing a fair amount of inter-node communication in order to ensure that access to the sequence is serialized appropriately.  That's going to make this significantly more expensive than a normal sequence.  If you need to guarantee order, though, it's probably the most efficient approach that you're going to have.

Comment: Our DBAs have locked/cached the sequences... is this my only option?

Comment: @BrienMalone - It's certainly the best option.  You can specify a `cache` for a sequence that has `order` specified if that is the DBA's concern.  I'm not sure what a "locked" sequence would be.  If this is a requirement, I would expect the DBAs to be fine creating this one particular sequence as `order` rather than the default `noorder`.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that an attached timestamp on a row is generated at time of the insert or update, but the time that the actual change to the database takes place is when the commit happens - which, depending on the complexity of the transactions, row 1 might get inserted before row2, but gett committed after.

The only thing I am aware of in Oracle across the nodes that guarantees the order is the SCN that Oracle attaches to the transaction, and by which transactions in a RAC environment can be ordered for things like Streams replication.

Answer (score 0):

1000ms? It is one sec, isn't it? IMHO it is a lot. If you really need precise time, then simply give up the idea of global time. Generate timestamps on log server and assume that each log server has it's own local time. Read something about Lamport's time, if you need some theory. But maybe the source of your problem is somewhere else. RAC synchronises time between nodes, and it would log some bigger discrepancy.

If two consecutive events are logged by two different connections, is the same thread using both connections? Or are those evens passed to background threads and then those threads write into the database? i.e. is it logged sequentially or in parallel?